# My sponsor currently does not have a job

Tags: visas, schengen, sweden

tl;dr: Planning to travel to Sweden for 2 weeks. Sponsor is still a student so no current job/income. But he does have a decent amount of money in savings. Should I still pursue my application?

Hello there, so I'm new to this. Well, this has been bothering for me a few days so I figured it's time to ask for opinions. The situation: I plan to travel to Sweden for two weeks. I have a friend there who will sponsor me (will pay for my expenses and accommodations). He currently does not have a job since he's still studying. However, he does have savings (inheritance from when his father died) and does have a house of his own (fully paid, no loans, also inherited from his father). He also gets some passive money from stocks. He has sent me bank statements, and other related documents.

I'm a bit paranoid about my chances since he does not currently have an income yet and all. I know this really lowers my chances of getting a visa. So should I still pursue this or will this be just suicide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to be clear to immigration officers what the purpose of your visit is. Why are you traveling to Sweden for 2 weeks? Is it for tourism? Is it for vacation? If so, make sure that all your documents clearly point to that intent. If that is the case, then you should not be worried.

What is crucial is that you show that you intend to return home after the 2 week trip especially if you pursue the application for a tourist visa. Documents you can show to support this are enrollment certificates for education in your home country, your paychecks (to show that you have a job that you want to return to), property, etc. These all clarify your intent not to overstay your visa.

Good luck!
.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This greatly helps! I've already indicated on my cover letter (and he, on his invitation) that the purpose of the visit (visit him to spend Christmas & New Year and visit museums). I do hope it goes well (enough).

Anyway, thank you for the help again!

Comment: That sounds great. If you could include a clear itinerary to your visit, I think that would help too! Don't worry! :)

Comment: I hope so! And yes, I have also attached a detailed itinerary. I'll see how this goes. Thanks!

Comment: @DrewBarieCajandab if you are happy with this answer, please MARK it with the check mark. Thanks